# C++ (WINAPI) Window with animated image

Tags: c++, image, winapi, animation, background

I have created a border-less window and I want to show an animated image (the earth rotating infinitely) like in this image:

[image: Window example]

I have the animation as an **.avi** file and also as a folder of about 40 images and I don't know if there's any way of doing this (if possible without using two much space or memory). The AVI file has a black background behind the Earth and the PNG file has a transparent background. There's also a nice blur which I would like to keep? What do you think?

Comment: Draw the next frame of the AVI file onto a memory DC using a timer, then invalidate the control to force repaint. In your paint handler, use `TransparentBlt` to copy your memory DC content onto your control, using black as transparent color. Unfortunately, your Earth is partially black. There are multiple solutions to address this, I'd change the background color in the AVI to e.g. purple.
 AVI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
 TransparentBlt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Doing this with raw GDI/GDI+ APIs is possible, but complex.  There are other toolkits (Direct2D, XAML) that wrap up much of the complexity.  What Windows versions do you need to run on?

Comment: Well, at least for Windows XP

Comment: If you only have 40 frames then I'd suggest storing them as resources with proper alpha channels rather than try to kludge an AVI to have transparency. GDI+ can load a PNG with alpha from resources, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI for an example.

Comment: How about creating a normal animation control and use SetWindowRgn to clip it. I never tried this, but may work.